# Why would this dplyr mutate statement result in invalid 'length' argument error?

Tags: r, dplyr

The below reproducible code works fine until it gets to the last `mutate` statement for `ClassDecrease`. It gives me the *invalid 'length' argument* error. What am I doing wrong? `ClassDecrease` should give me these results:

```
0
0
0
0
0
-1
```

and not this which it currently gives:

```
0
0
0
0
1
1
```

Reproducible code:

```
library(dplyr)

data <- 
  data.frame(
    Element = c("D","D","R","D","C","C"),
    SplitCode = c(0,0,0,0,1,1)
  )


Class_to_Count <- 1

excelCopy <- data %>% 
  group_by(Element) %>% 
  mutate(PreSplitClass = row_number()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(ClassAtSplit =
           case_when(
             SplitCode == 0 ~ as.integer(0), # This eliminates checking for > 0
             SplitCode > lag(SplitCode) ~ PreSplitClass, # if > previous value
             SplitCode == lag(SplitCode) ~ lag(PreSplitClass) # if equal (0s are avoided)
           )
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    LowClassSplit =
      case_when(
        SplitCode > lag(SplitCode) & SplitCode == Class_to_Count ~ PreSplitClass,
        SplitCode == lag(SplitCode) & SplitCode == Class_to_Count ~ lag(PreSplitClass),
        TRUE ~ 0L
      )
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    GrossSubclass =
      case_when(
        LowClassSplit == Class_to_Count ~ PreSplitClass,
        TRUE ~ 0L
      )
    ) %>%
  group_by(Element) %>% 
  mutate(NetSubclass = cumsum(LowClassSplit == Class_to_Count)
         ) %>%
  
  ungroup %>%
  
  rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(
      ClassSubclass = sum(LowClassSplit, NetSubclass/10)
    ) %>%
  
  ungroup %>%
  
  mutate(ApplyToNoSplits = ClassSubclass[match(PreSplitClass, GrossSubclass)] * !SplitCode) %>%
  
  ungroup %>%
  
  # Here's the error:
  mutate(ClassDecrease = 
           case_when(
            LowClassSplit == Class_to_Count ~ (integer(trunc(ClassSubclass)) - PreSplitClass),
            TRUE ~ 0L
           )
         )
  
  print.data.frame(excelCopy)
```

Comment: Does as.integer() give the result you want? For me that removes the error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replacing `integer` with `as.integer` in your code gives what you expect.

```
case_when(
  excelCopy$LowClassSplit == Class_to_Count ~ (as.integer(trunc(excelCopy$ClassSubclass)) - excelCopy$PreSplitClass),
  TRUE ~ 0L)
[1]  0  0  0  0  0 -1
```

Comment: OK, and I ran ?integer and ?as.integer to understand the difference. "integer" creates a integer vector of the specified length with each element of the vector equal to 0, whereas as.integer attempts to coerce its argument to be of integer type. Also, trunc() returns class double instead of integer so in my case I need to wrap trunc() with as.integer()

as.integer attempts to coerce its argument to be of integer type.